# CSS, HTML : inside bootstrap div element, fill background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fill the background of bootstrap jumbotron

My code is

```
.jumbotron {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 2.1428571435;
}

.jumbotron  div#bg:after {
    content: "";
    background: url("image.jpg");
    opacity: 0.2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;   
}
```

And the element I am trying to fill

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div id="bg"></div>
  <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="http://github.com" target="blank">GitHub</a></p>
</div>
```

But this code fills the entire page, while what I want is only filling the selected element.

How should I do this with CSS?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just applying your background image directly to the hero unit/jumbotron?

Comment: `.jumbotron #bg` should work and try to add height and width property

Comment: @TiesonT. I believe the reason is that the opacity should only apply to the background image

Comment: @koala_dev Sounds reasonable, but this seems like more work than just editing the image itself to be translucent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to `.jumbotron` to restrain the absolutely positioned element to its bounds, also you don't need the empty div, you can just use the `:after` pseudo-element on the `.jumbotron` itself:

```
 .jumbotron {
     position: relative;
     background: none;
     padding: 5px;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: 200;
     line-height: 2.1428571435;
 }
 .jumbotron:after {
     content:"";
     background: url("image.jpg");
     opacity: 0.2;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: -1;
 }
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/VkxMS/)**

Comment: how compatible this solution is? Does anyone know which browsers it supports? cheers

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike You can [go here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Browser_compatibility) to check the browser compatibility table for `:after`, everything else in this solution is standard.